# Is it permissible to listen to a woman speaking over a song if that is part of the song?

Tags: halacha, women

Consider this following song, [Presence of Mind by Dynazty](https://youtu.be/JAmFSftWI5Q?t=122) (I have marked it to the point relevant to my question). At this point, a male speaks over the song, and these are part of the song's lyrics. However, it is not, strictly speaking, *singing*.

Suppose a woman were to perform that part of the song (or any other song with such a part to it). Is this acceptable for a man to listen to because it is not singing, or unacceptable because it is analogous to/very close to singing?

Note: The genre of song is heavy metal and may be considered disallowed by some authorities for that reason, regardless of who is singing it. For our purposes, assume an arbitrary permissible song.

Comment: While halacha generally understood to prohibit listening to women only while singing, see Kedushin Chapter 4 (toward the begining of the chapter in Gemara, in the "shviskel" story) where it prohibits GREETING a woman on this basis implying that not only singing, and maybe any voice, is prohibitted.

Comment: Rap music might raise a similar question